# PHP Configuration Issue

Tags: php, apache

I apologize far in advance if I'm barking up the wrong tree or it's been answered somewhere else but I have no idea where to begin.  I'm leery even putting up publicly accessible info up but I need some clues.  And yes, I know I shouldn't be developing on the same system as the production, but this is a special 1-off case where I'm in a humongous rush and my normal "vpn to my personal network" is broken.

The problem: I keep getting errors like the below in my developer sites log.  Normally I would be whatever, just someone testing the waters (like the xmlrpc not found errors) but I'm concerned I have a configuration issue with Apache/PHP that's allowing cross-site file access.

Example dev.somedomain.org has /path/to/dev

```
[php:error] [pid 166479] [client 192.36.109.84:22027] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught Error: Failed opening required 'yykprd.php' ... /{sitelibpath}/db_connect.php:10\nStack trace:\n#0 /{path}/{devdir}/header.php(9): include()\n#1 /{path}/dev/index.php(9): include('...')\n#2 {main}\n  thrown in /{path}lib/{proddir}/db_connect.php on line 10, referer: http://{NOT THE DEV OR PROD SITE}.US
```

Another similar error

```
[Sat Feb 10 14:30:58.352131 2024] [php:warn] [pid 173467] [client 46.246.8.115:54440] PHP Warning:  require_once(yykprd.php): Failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /{path}/{sitelibdir}/db_connect.php on line 10, referer: http://{NOT THE DEV OR PROD SITE}.US
```

My concern mainly surrounds the fact that my prod and dev sites are having their files access from other configured sites that have no configuration to reference these files/directories.  I fear I may have a security risk due to a misconfig of apache/php.

The db_connect.php file exists outside of the web-root directories and are accessible via a set_include_path in the site's files.  Below is the beginning of the db_connect.php file.  The only thing I've not done before on other sites is use the str_starts_with to simplify dev/prd as they use the same db_connect script but with different creds.

```
<?php

if(!session_id()){
    session_start();
}

if (str_starts_with($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'], 'dev')) {
        require_once('yykdev.php');
} else {
        require_once('yykprd.php');
}

openLink();

function openLink() {
```

Comment: It seems your script can't find the file `yykprd.php`. Is it in the same directory as your `db_connect.php`? If not, specify the full path to  `yykprd.php`.

Comment: It would seem that when you're developing on the same system as you run for production, `$_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']` does not start with `dev` (I would imagine it probably returns the production host name)

Comment: @nick That would be fine, but I'm seeing this error in the dev.hostname.org apache error log vs prod.  Additionally the referrers are hosts configured on this server, but not related to dev.hostname.org or www.hostname.org, they are someothersite.us